# RecyclerView with more that one row per item doesn't inflate divider

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView's here and there and I found that when list item have only one row `DividerItemDecoration` works perfectly fine, but when it comes to two-rows items it just doesn't show up.

Here I inflate it:

```
CenaListRecAdapter mAdapter = new CenaListRecAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cenaLokalList, point);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
```

and standard `DividerItemDecoration` class:

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
        android.R.attr.listDivider
};

public static final int HORIZONTAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL;

public static final int VERTICAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL;

private Drawable mDivider;

private int mOrientation;

public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation) {
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
    mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
    a.recycle();
    setOrientation(orientation);
}

public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    if (orientation != HORIZONTAL_LIST && orientation != VERTICAL_LIST) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid orientation");
    }
    mOrientation = orientation;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        drawVertical(c, parent);
    } else {
        drawHorizontal(c, parent);
    }
}

public void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        final int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

public void drawHorizontal(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
    final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin;
        final int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, int itemPosition, RecyclerView parent) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
    } else {
        outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
    }
}
```

}

**edit**: that's how my row view item looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:transitionName="obrazek"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/nazwa"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/odleglosc"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nazwa"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:clickable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=" "
            android:id="@+id/cena"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nazwa"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found answer by myself.

If You're using RecyclerView in Activity (not Fragment), then `context` for your `DividerItemDecoration` should be `this`, not `getApplicationContext()` - You use that in anonymous classes - and in Fragment classes You should use `getActivity()`.

Oh, and it's good to set decoration right after the `LayoutManager` and set adapter after that - even if Your list is empty. It just works that way, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help, from the official documentation:

> All ItemDecorations are drawn in the order they were added, before the
>   item views, in `ItemDecoration#onDraw()` and after the items in `ItemDecoration#onDrawOver(Canvas, RecyclerView, RecyclerView.State)`

You should be overriding the `onDrawOver` method instead.

Comment: I tried it and effect is the same, but I override `public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent)`

Comment: I just tried it here, and it works just fine. Are you sure you are doing everything correctly? Maybe rebuild the project, or consider updating your version of the recyclerview library

Comment: I'm building on v7:22.2.0 - may that be the cause?

Comment: Ah. Seen your answer. I apparently overlooked the `getApplicationContext` part. Yes, when you are working with any UI component, you should always use a UI context.